# How to create a function in JavaScript takes numeral with digits instead of separators?

Tags: javascript, function, number-formatting

I want to create a function that takes a numeral (just digits without separators, e.g. `19093`) and returns the standard way of reading a number, complete with punctuation.

what i tried to do

```js
function sayNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


function test(num, expect) {
  const result = sayNumber(num);
  const pass = result === expect;
  console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${num} => ${result}`);
  return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0, "0");
failures += !test(100, "100");
failures += !test(1000, "1,000");
failures += !test(10000, "10,000");
failures += !test(100000, "100,000");
failures += !test(1000000, "1,000,000");
failures += !test(10000000, "10,000,000");
if (failures) {
  console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
  console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

newested changes and error messages when compiled.

```js
function sayNumber(BigInt) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(BigInt);
}

function test(BigInt, expect) {
  const result = sayNumber(BigInt);
  const pass = result === expect;
  console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${BigInt} => ${result}`);
  return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0, "0");
failures += !test(11, "11");
failures += !test(14, "14");
failures += !test(15, "15");

if (failures) {
  console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
  console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

Error messages

```
✓ 0 => 0
✓ 11 => 11
✓ 14 => 14
✓ 15 => 15
All tests passed
FAILED: Expected: 'Zero.', instead got: '0'
FAILED: Expected: 'Eleven.', instead got: '11'
FAILED: Expected: 'Fourteen.', instead got: '14'
FAILED: Expected: 'Fifteen.', instead got: '15'
FAILED: Expected: 'Forty-three.', instead got: '43'
FAILED: Expected: 'Fifty.', instead got: '50'
FAILED: Expected: 'One thousand and one.', instead got: '1,001'
FAILED:
```

The expected values are the ones the IDE needs to read and expects, currently its not doing that either.

Comment: Have you had a look at the native [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)? `return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(num);`. That being said, your code seems to pass all tests, once we replace `x` with `num`, in the `sayNumber` function

Comment: @blex ok what i am aiming to achieve here is Must read any number from 0 to 999,999,999,999,999. currently my code does not do that and need some help and yes i remove return x with num and still not able to get Must read any number from 0 to 999,999,999,999,999.

Comment: The page mentioned by blex can help you with that. Formatting numbers is a thing that depends on the locale, so there is no way to do that universally.

Comment: What is the specific issue?

Comment: `x.toString` should be `num.toString`

Comment: JavaScript numbers have a limit of about 15 digits precision. If you want longer numbers you need to use `BigInt`.

Comment: @Barmar, have tried to use BigInt and still not getting this right. Have a look at the my newest change and see what is expected when compiled the error messages

Comment: I don't see a change.

Comment: Now I see it. Why don't you make it a Stack Snippet so we can execute it?

Comment: @Barmar maybe you might now understands the issue i am facing have a look at the amended code again

Comment: You're not using the `BigInt` class anywhere, all you did was rename the parameter to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) class. Renaming the parameter from `num` to `BigInt` doesn't cause it to be a big integer.

You can write a BigInt literal by putting `n` at the end of the number.

```js
function sayNumber(num) {
  return BigInt(num).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


function test(num, expect) {
  const result = sayNumber(num);
  const pass = result === expect;
  console.log(`${pass ? "✓" : "ERROR ====>"} ${num} => ${result}`);
  return pass;
}

let failures = 0;
failures += !test(0, "0");
failures += !test(100, "100");
failures += !test(1000, "1,000");
failures += !test(10000, "10,000");
failures += !test(100000, "100,000");
failures += !test(1000000, "1,000,000");
failures += !test(10000000, "10,000,000");
failures += !test(999999999999999n, "999,999,999,999,999");
if (failures) {
  console.log(`${failures} test(s) failed`);
} else {
  console.log("All tests passed");
}
```

Comment: now it makes sense, saw what i did because on my return type object instead of using BigInt i have tried to use return new Intl....... Thank you so much at least saw my weakness was on this program.